# How to resolve dependence of libmono-winforms2.0-cil

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, asus

On a new lubuntu 16.04 installation, I need to install AsusWebstorage.

After downloading the AsusWebstorage deb packet,I am trying to install the software with the packet installation software.  However, I get an error message specifying that the dependencies to libmono-winforms2.0-cil cannot be satisfied.

I looked on the web for instructions to install the libmono-winforms2.0-cil piece of software but none of the instructions I found worked.

I read alone the way that the software has been removed from the official ppa less than a year ago and I should be looking towards private ppa.

Help in identifying a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`libmono-winforms2.0-cil` is available in 14.04, so the best thing to do would be to install that instead of 16.04, though it will reach EOL in about a year...

Comment: FYI Lubuntu 14.04 reached EOL in April 2017.  Unlike Ubuntu 14.04 which as you said has about another year.

Comment: I just realised I didn't thank you for your answer.  Thank you for having taken the time to reply to my question.